# How to get the value of user input field using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

i am trying to fetch api-data as per user input field. how to fetch the value of these data?

my api end-point like this  "http://localhost:8000/api/p_list?search=" . whenever user input the value, endpoint is like this "http://localhost:8000/api/p_list?search=01" here is the input field value is "01". i want to get the value of the result.

i am probably new to reactjs. i tried something below like this but this is the static API url what i'm trying to fetch. i am not sure how to fetch dynamic url as per user input field.

it would be great if anybody could help me out what i am trying to solve. thank you so much in advance.

./src/productList.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Contacts from './productListHook.js';


export default class App  extends Component{

   state = {
       contacts: []
   }

   componentDidMount() {
       fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/p_list?search=')
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then((data) => {
         this.setState({ contacts: data })
       })
       .catch(console.log)
     }

   render(){
   return(

       <Contacts contacts={this.state.contacts} />
   )
}
}
```

./src/ProductListHook.js

```
import React from 'react'

    const Contacts = ({ contacts }) => {
      return (

        <section class="product_list section_padding">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="product_sidebar">
                        <div class="single_sedebar">
                            <form action="#">
                                <input type="text" name="#" placeholder="Search keyword"/>
                                <i class="ti-search"></i>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div class="product_list">
                        <div class="row">

                        {contacts.map((contact) => (

                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-9">
                                <div class="single_product_item">
                                    <img src={contact.image} alt="" class="img-fluid" />
                                    <h3> <a href={contact.url}>{contact.title}</a> </h3>
                                    <p>From ${contact.price}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            ))}

                        </div>
                        <div class="load_more_btn text-center">
                            <a href="#" class="btn_3">Load More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>

      )
    };

export default Contacts
```

Comment: you need to pass input value to request url?

Comment: You can create a state that contains users input. then it will be stored and usable for you call.

Comment: is this answer what i am trying to solve is "https://therichpost.com/get-input-field-value-button-click-reactjs/"  ? @happyZZR1400

Comment: i am probably new to reactjs, i am not sure how to do this. can you please run this code on sandbox environmental ? @TheoWckr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi Please check this complete example:** It is taking user id from user using the textbox and after button click it calls api with that user id and get all posts by that user. After that it shows all post title on the screen.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

function PostListPageByUser() {
    const [posts, setPost] = useState([]);
    const [userId, setUserId] = useState([]);
    let signal = axios.CancelToken.source();

    function handleChange(event) {
        setUserId(event.target.value);
    }

    function handleClick(event) {
        axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=${userId}`, {
            cancelToken: signal.token,
        })
            .then(res => {
                const posts = res.data;
                setPost(posts);
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <span>Enter User Id</span>
            <input type="text" onChange={handleChange}/>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Get Posts By User</button>
            <ul>
                {
                    posts.map(post => <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>)
                }
            </ul>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
export default PostListPageByUser;
```

**As per your comment on my answer I added this example with form submit:**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

function PostListPageByUser() {
    const [posts, setPost] = useState([]);
    const [userId, setUserId] = useState([]);
    let signal = axios.CancelToken.source();

    function handleChange(event) {
        setUserId(event.target.value);
    }

    function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=${userId}`, {
            cancelToken: signal.token,
        })
            .then(res => {
                const posts = res.data;
                setPost(posts);
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <span>Enter User Id</span>
            <input type="text" onChange={handleChange}/>
            <button type="submit">Get Posts By User</button>
            <ul>
                {
                    posts.map(post => <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>)
                }
            </ul>
        </form>
    );
}

export default PostListPageByUser;
```

Comment: okay! if i have  <form action=""> , then what should i pass inside the action?

Comment: hi for form, you should use
<form onSubmit={handleClick}>
and button type will be submit as below:
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

Comment: hi , it's doesn't taking any input in search fields insted of it taking "Submit" as argument.

Comment: hi I have added another example that works fine. please check that.

Comment: why did you end the "</form>" tag in the last section? you can put the "</form>" tag after end of "</button>" tag. is that cause any error?

Comment: no it will not create any error but it may misbehave. usually form should contain all input controls like textbox or radio or button.

Comment: please take a look at this link --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61283798/how-to-fetch-api-data-in-a-series-reactjs

Comment: checked it.. what should I do there?

Comment: i was asking to you whether i made mistake in that problem, however i got resolved. thank you for your response.

Comment: After asking you, I tried to fix your code and change a lot. Thanks anyway.

Comment: hey there. can you take a look at another link --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61301851/how-to-render-to-a-page-whenever-user-click-to-a-dynamic-url-reactjs/61301972?

Comment: Yes I looked it

Answer (score 0):

Your `Contacts` component has the input but the API call is being made in its parent `App` component.

What you need to do is pass another `prop` to `Contacts` that is a *function* that will be called everytime the input state inside `Contacts` change.

Example:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  ...

  search(inputValue){
    fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/p_list?search=${inputValue}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({ contacts: data })
    })
    .catch(console.log)
  }

  render() {
    <Contacts contacts={this.state.contacts} onSearch={search}/>
  }
```

Now inside `Contacts` component:

```
const Contacts = ({contacts, onSearch}) => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  return (
    ...
    <input onChange={
           (e) => {
            setSearch(search);
            onSearch(e.currentTarget.value);
           }
         } value={search} .../>
    ...
   )
}
```

I just wrote the conceptual code to make it work, it's missing `bind` and the other specific implementation about your project.

I strongly recommend you to implement a logic inside onSearch function to delay the API call because it will be triggered in new letter typed in the input. This can overload the api.

Hope it helps.