# how to fetch series api-data ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to fetch a series api-data. as per below api-data each series have their own data, for e.g a series "bannerData" have their data id,banner_title... and next series "homecatData" have their data like id,category_title... and so on up to last series.

in my case, endpoint api is "http://localhost:8000/api/homepage/"

how to fetch this data in reactjs?

i am probably new to reactjs. it would be great if anybody could help me out what i am trying to solve is. thank you so much in advance.

```
{
    "bannerData": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "banner_title": "CORONA sell",
            "banner_image": "http://localhost:8000/media/hero_man.png",
            "discount_price": 86,
            "product_category": "7"
        }
    ],
    "homecatData": [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "category_title": "new-arrival",
            "category_slug": "new-arrival",
            "category_description": "",
            "category_image": "http://localhost:8000/media/cat2.jpg"
        },
    ],
    "homeproductData": [
        {
            "_id": 9,
            "product_title": "product05",
            "product_price": 21,
            "product_image": "http://localhost:8000/media/product4_JOvGftO.png",
            "product_new": false
        },
        {
            "_id": 7,
            "product_title": "product03",
            "product_price": 21,
            "product_image": "http://localhost:8000/media/product3.png",
            "product_new": false
        },

    ],
}
```

Comment: You need to show what you've tried. There are many ways to do it. Show us how you are trying to do it.

Comment: take a look this link https://pastebin.com/WM9tPwsL @TJBlackman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways fetch data in `react`. One of the most common way is to fetch using a package called `axios`. Since you are using a class-based component, It will look like this.

Here's a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-rain-9dd65?file=/src/App.js)
as per your request.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from 'axios'
import Data from "./contact.js";

    export default class App extends Component {
      state = {
        results: [],
        isLoading: false,
      };

      componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
      }

      fetchData = async () => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
        try {
          const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/homepage/");
          this.setState({ results: response, isLoading: false });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      };

      render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
          return "Loading...";
        }
        return <Data results={this.state.results} />;
      }
    }
```

You are trying to map an `object` in your `contact.js` file. You can always destructure them or you have to explicitly access the array you want using the dot operator and also in `react` you have to use `className` instead of just `class` when using it.

import React from "react";

```
const Data = ({ results }) => {
  if (!results) {
    return "";
  }
  const { bannerData, homecatData } = results;
  return (
    <div>
      <center>
        <h1>Banner Data</h1>
      </center>
      {bannerData.map((bannerData) => (
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{bannerData.banner_title}</h5>
            <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">
              {bannerData.banner_image}
            </h6>
            <p className="card-text"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}

      <center>
        <h1>Home Category Data</h1>
      </center>
      {homecatData.map((homecatData) => (
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{homecatData.category_title}</h5>
            <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">
              {homecatData.category_image}
            </h6>
            <p className="card-text"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Data;
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. next how to map the fetch data in my "./src/contact.js" and how to pass the value as a parameter?

Comment: I see that you have already mapped those data in your `contact.js` file. Is it now working?

Comment: `response.json() ` axios does not have .json method

Comment: You did not mention the error. What do you imply by clean code? I just forgot to `await` a `promise`. I have only added a `fetchData()`  function apart from your original code.

Comment: @AjinKabeer add minimal code, so that OP can look and start working. Btter add sandbox example, if too big. hard to debug and trace back.

Comment: Yeah sure. Thanks @xdeepakv

Comment: Here's a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-rain-9dd65?file=/src/App.js)
as per your request. @SatyajitBarik

Comment: okay! perfect on sandbox. when i am fetching on my local api, i am getiing a blank page(nothing output usually). i think data are not loading as expected while fetching.

Comment: Alright. Can you add `console.log(response)` after `const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/homepage/")` to see if there's any request being sent from the browser?

Comment: Added, console.log(response) after const response = await . i checked,  i am not getting any response from **axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/homepage/")** from browser

Comment: Can you check the network tab in your chrome Devtools after refreshing your page to see if the browser sends any request?

Comment: i think there is something wrong while fetching the api data.

Comment: Okay. Try remove the `get` method. =>           `const response = await axios("http://localhost:8000/api/homepage/");`

Comment: nupe! i am still getting same error. can you please try with this api --> https://api.whatdoestrumpthink.com/api/v1/quotes/  in your sandbox? there is two series in this api as you can see.

Comment: Yes. I have added the link in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-rain-9dd65?file=/src/App.js). You can check the console which can be found at the bottom.

Comment: wait, i am giving you my remote server. please try this out here on my machine. before we begin please install anydesk remote desktop applicaion on your machine. @AjinKabeer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211920/discussion-between-ajin-kabeer-and-satyajit-barik).

Comment: can you please take a look at this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61301851/how-to-render-to-a-page-whenever-user-click-to-a-dynamic-url-reactjs

Comment: hey there. please come to chatbox. i have one more problem in reactjs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212058/discussion-between-ajin-kabeer-and-satyajit-barik).

Answer (score 1):

You could fetch from each main json data (bannerData,homecatData,homeproductData)

```
export const fetchbannerData = ()  =>{
        return fetch(baseurls+'bannerData')
            .then(response => {
                    if (response.ok) {
                        return response;
                    } else {
                        var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
                        error.response = response;
                        throw error;
                    }
                },
                error => {
                    var errmess = new Error(error.message);
                    throw errmess;
                })
            .then(response => response.json())
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Axios would help you to fetch api  data.
type npm I axios on terminal to use axis to fetch data

visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios to install axis and learn how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Using fetch native javascript. You can customize using `useEffect`, `useState`, or `async-await`.

```js
//const React = require("react")
//const ReactDOM = require("react-dom")

const baseURL = "https://api.whatdoestrumpthink.com/api/v1/quotes/";
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    quotes: [],
    loading: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getQuotes();
  }
  getQuotes() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    try {
      fetch(baseURL)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
          this.setState({
            quotes: response.messages.personalized,
            loading: false,
          });
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      this.setState({ loading: false });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { quotes, loading } = this.state;
    if (loading) {
      return "Loading Quotes...";
    }
    return <Quotes quotes={quotes} />;
  }
}
function Quotes({ quotes = [] }) {
  return quotes.map((quote, index) => (<div key={index}>{quote}</div>));
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root-app"));
```

```html
<div id="root-app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```