# how to fetch api filter-data in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have endpoint of filter data like this much-

> **localhost:8000/api/p_list?product_category=&color=&size=**

whenever user filter the data the output would something look like this,

> localhost:8000/api/p_list?product_category=1&color=1&size=2

the output of results comes according filter id as per user request to get. how to fetch the value whenever user request the id as per filter in reactjs?

i am probably new to reactjs. i am trying to solve this problem, it would be great if anybody could help me out what i am trying to do. thank you so much in advance.

*my method how i tried to solve,*

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

function PostListPageByUser() {
    const [posts, setPost] = useState([]);
    const [userId, setUserId] = useState([]);
    let signal = axios.CancelToken.source();

    function handleChange(event) {
        setUserId(event.target.value);
    }

    function handleClick(event) {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/p_list?product_category=${id}&color=${Id}&size=${Id}`, {
            cancelToken: signal.token,
        })
            .then(res => {
                const posts = res.data;
                setPost(posts);
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

 return (
  <div>

        <div class="product_sidebar">


              <div class="single_sedebar">
                  <div class="select_option">
                      <div class="select_option_list">Category <i class="right fas fa-caret-down"></i> </div>
                      <div class="select_option_dropdown">

                            {product_categoryData.map(product_categoryData => (

                              <p onClick={useEffect}>{product_categoryData.category_title}</p>

                              ))} 
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>


              <div class="single_sedebar">
                  <div class="select_option">
                      <div class="select_option_list">Color <i class="right fas fa-caret-down"></i> </div>
                      <div class="select_option_dropdown">
                          {filter_colorData.map(filter_colorData => (

                              <p onClick={useEffect}>{filter_colorData.color_title}</p>

                          ))}
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>


              <div class="single_sedebar">
                  <div class="select_option">
                      <div class="select_option_list">Size <i class="right fas fa-caret-down"></i> </div>
                      <div class="select_option_dropdown">
                          {filter_sizeData.map(filter_sizeData => (

                              <p onClick={useEffect}>{filter_sizeData.size_title}</p>

                          ))}
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

        </div>

  </div>
  );
};

export default PostListPageByUser;
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem here, Are you not able to filter, Or show the data? Also you can use params in get call to pass your data!

Answer (score 0):

try storing the values of category size and color in state and make the api call in a useEffect hook that will run every-time the state of one of these values changes.

in generel:

```js
function PostListPageByUser() {
    const [posts, setPost] = useState([]);
    const [category, setCategory] = useState('');
    const [color, setColor] = useState('');
    const [size, setSize] = useState('');
    let signal = axios.CancelToken.source();

    function handleChange(event) {
        setUserId(event.target.value);
    }
    useEffect(() => { axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/p_list?product_category=${category}&color=${color}&size=${size}`, {
            cancelToken: signal.token,
        })
            .then(res => {
                const posts = res.data;
                setPost(posts);
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })}, [size,color,category])
```

and in your form modify mutate the state

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

function PostListPageByUser() {
    const [posts, setPost] = useState([]);
    const [userId, setUserId] = useState([]);
    const [productCategory, setProductCategory] = useState(null);
    const [productColor, setProductColor] = useState(null);
    const [productSize, setProductSize] = useState(null);
    let signal = axios.CancelToken.source();

    function handleChange(event) {
        setUserId(event.target.value);
    }

    function handleClick() {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/p_list?product_category=${productCategory}&color=${productColor}&size=${productSize}`, {
            cancelToken: signal.token,
        })
            .then(res => {
                const posts = res.data;
                setPost(posts);
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
    useEffect(
    () => {
      handleClick();
    },
    [productCategory,productColor,productSize],
  );

 return (
  <div>

        <div class="product_sidebar">


              <div class="single_sedebar">
                  <div class="select_option">
                      <div class="select_option_list">Category <i class="right fas fa-caret-down"></i> </div>
                      <div class="select_option_dropdown">

                            {product_categoryData.map(product_categoryData => (

                              <p onClick={setProductCategory(product_categoryData.category_title)}>{product_categoryData.category_title}</p>

                              ))} 
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>


              <div class="single_sedebar">
                  <div class="select_option">
                      <div class="select_option_list">Color <i class="right fas fa-caret-down"></i> </div>
                      <div class="select_option_dropdown">
                          {filter_colorData.map(filter_colorData => (

                              <p onClick={setProductColor(filter_colorData.color_title)}>{filter_colorData.color_title}</p>

                          ))}
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>


              <div class="single_sedebar">
                  <div class="select_option">
                      <div class="select_option_list">Size <i class="right fas fa-caret-down"></i> </div>
                      <div class="select_option_dropdown">
                          {filter_sizeData.map(filter_sizeData => (

                              <p onClick={setProductSize(filter_sizeData.size_title)}>{filter_sizeData.size_title}</p>

                          ))}
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

        </div>

  </div>
  );
};
```

Below step should happen :-

1. Onclick set state
   2.state change call API

Comment: product_categoryData, filter_colorData, filter_sizeData are not defined.

Comment: i took these value as constant parameter but still this doesn't working.    const Data = ({ results }) => {
  if(!results){
    return ''
  }
  const { product_categoryData, product_priceData, filter_colorData, filter_sizeData} = results;

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why your `onClick` prop is not firing when it's changed.

1. You are calling `useEffect` directly in your `onClick` even though you didn't define it in your code.
2. You are not using `useState` to set category, colour or size anywhere in your code to use it to make async calls.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function PostListPageByUser() {
  const [posts, setPost] = useState([]);
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState([]);
  const [categoryTitle, setCategoryTitle] = useState("");
  const [color, setColor] = useState("");
  const [size, setSize] = useState("");
  let signal = axios.CancelToken.source();

  function handleChange(event) {
    setUserId(event.target.value);
  }

  async function handleClick(event) {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `http://localhost:8000/api/p_list?product_category=${categoryTitle}&color=${color}&size=${size}`,
        {
          cancelToken: signal.token,
        }
      );
      setPost(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    this.handleClick();
  }, [categoryTitle, color, size]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div class="product_sidebar">
        <div class="single_sedebar">
          <div class="select_option">
            <div class="select_option_list">
              Category <i class="right fas fa-caret-down"></i>{" "}
            </div>
            <div class="select_option_dropdown">
              {product_categoryData.map((product_categoryData) => (
                <p
                  onClick={setCategoryTitle(
                    product_categoryData.category_title
                  )}
                >
                  {product_categoryData.category_title}
                </p>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="single_sedebar">
          <div class="select_option">
            <div class="select_option_list">
              Color <i class="right fas fa-caret-down"></i>{" "}
            </div>
            <div class="select_option_dropdown">
              {filter_colorData.map((filter_colorData) => (
                <p onClick={setColor(filter_colorData.color_title)}>
                  {filter_colorData.color_title}
                </p>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="single_sedebar">
          <div class="select_option">
            <div class="select_option_list">
              Size <i class="right fas fa-caret-down"></i>{" "}
            </div>
            <div class="select_option_dropdown">
              {filter_sizeData.map((filter_sizeData) => (
                <p onClick={setSize(filter_sizeData.size_title)}>
                  {filter_sizeData.size_title}
                </p>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PostListPageByUser;
```

Comment: as like previous, i am getting a blank page instead. i am new to reactjs. i am not getting the point where i am doing thing wrong in my code.

Comment: Yes, I understand and it's okay. Slowly, you'll get better if you understand the mistakes.

Comment: The reasons I think you are getting a blank page is that, you will need to specify the path in your `<Route />` component.

Comment: hey there, can you please run this code on sandbox environmental and test it?